# How can I mute music and sounds while playing?

Tags: pokemon-go

The app starts up with background music etc., and this isn't always a good idea to have on - how can I mute the game volume, without having to do so for all apps?

Comment: Why is Pokemon Go so popular? In terms of people asking questions

Comment: @Alex Because it's awesome.

Comment: @Alex - That would be a great question for the chat, you'll get a ton of replies. For me - its a way to get exercise while having fun with a new spin on a very popular collectible game. Though I haven't played Pokemon games since before there were EV values!

Comment: @Alex that's usually what happens when a new game is released. There is often a surge of new questions over the first few weeks that a game launches, before it (usually) subsides a bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tap the Pokeball at the bottom of your screen.

From there, tap Settings in the top right corner.

[image]

Once you're in the Settings menu, you can disable sounds using their appropriate checkboxes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, was going to add screenshots to my self-answer later but good to have it already done so fast :)

Comment: @Alok Yeah, sorry about that. I've been stalking the tag all day today. ^~^

Comment: Np, I was being lazy to do it myself asap; this will help others who just downloaded the app but are still at work >_>

Comment: Whenever I log out, the settings seem to reset back to default. It's annoying to turn off the music every time. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @CreativiTimothy Update your app. Should be patched in 0.29.2. Also, this technically belongs in a new question.

Comment: @KazWolfe I have 0.29.2 -- I guess if this doesn't fix within the next version, I'll ask a new question

Comment: @CreativiTimothy just a heads up but you will get down voted for that question. It's a bug in the game. We can't do anything to fix it sadly

Answer (score 1):

The red & white small pokeball icon in the bottom middle of the screen calls up a menu screen with various options such as Pokedex. On that screen, there is a further 'Settings' menu on the top right - which has the options to mute sound effects and music.